# JavaScript replaceWith eliminating /

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running the following code.

```
y = '<img class="field-tag" data-field-id="1">'

$html = $('<div />', { html: y });

t = `<img src="xyz"/>`

$html.find('.field-tag').each(function() {
   var $tag = $(this);
    $tag.replaceWith((t));
})
```

now `$html.html()` has the value `<img src="xyz">` . Not that the `/` is not there.

Why is the `/` getting eliminated ? What should I do to prevent this. I want the `/`.

Comment: The browser is normalizing your HTML.  You can't do that.

Comment: replaceWith generates DOM elements, their representation is going to be dependent on your browser.